# SQL LIKE search with multiple text boxes?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

[image]

Here is the code for my button.

```
private void btnStudentLookup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConnect = "Server=DESKTOP- 
        2Q73COU\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LoginApp;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnect);
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlConnection studentLookup = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
        {
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE [First Name] like '%" + txtFirstName.Text + "%';", studentLookup);

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dgvAdvisor.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

Everything above works. It filters out rows based on First Name. However, I'd like to filter out more than that so I add this to the line:

```
"SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE [First Name] like '%" + txtFirstName.Text + "%' OR [Last Name] like '%" + txtLastName.Text + "%';", studentLookup
```

Now it just doesn't do anything. No errors,no exceptions, nothing. Any advice?

Comment: which sql version?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Not too sure... I'm using SSMS

Comment: Run the same query against the database directly from SSMS and see if you are getting any results. Debug the code and see if data table has any rows after the query executed.

Comment: An **EMPRY** result is a perfectly LEGAL result. Are you absolutely sure that your query **MUST** return something other than empty?

Comment: I'm too lazy to find a proper/better way of doing it but can you try on SSMS if this query works for you? `SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE [First Name] IN(SELECT [First Name] FROM Main_Information  WHERE [First Name] LIKE '%replacetestvaluehere%') OR [Last Name] IN (SELECT [Last Name] FROM Main_Information  WHERE [Last Name] LIKE '%replacetestvaluehere%')`.

Comment: Two comments 1) always use parameterized queries 2) change case while passing parameters for the comparison. You may not get the correct result if case aren't matching

Comment: @P.Pat that worked in SSMS!

Comment: But be aware what `OR` statement implies so you might want to do some validations to properly filter out the things you only want to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query as below:

SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE [First Name] like '%" + txtFirstName.Text + "%' **AND** [Last Name] like '%" + txtLastName.Text + "%';", studentLookup

Use AND operator instead of OR.

Answer (score 0):

When test your application write in the `txtFirstName` textbox:

```
'; DELETE FROM Main_Information; --
```

And press "Submit" button.

if everything works then great, if not then use `SqlParameters` for building query with dynamic values

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    var query = @"
        SELECT * FROM Main_Information
        WHERE [First Name] LIKE @firstName AND [Last Name] LIKE @lastName";
    var parameters = new [] 
    {
        new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@firstName",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
            Value = $"%{txtFirstName.Text}%"
        },
        new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@lastName",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
            Value = $"%{txtLastName.Text}%"
        }
    }   

    command.CommandText = query;
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

    connection.Open();

    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    var data = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(data);
    dgvAdvisor.DataSource = data;
}
```